# Prefix function as a predicate for filter function

Tags: haskell, filter, predicate, prefix, infix-notation

Here is the type signature and the definition of the `filter` function from *Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!*:

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' _ [] = []
filter' p (x:xs)
    | p x = x : filter' p xs
    | otherwise = filter' p xs
```

An usage example in the book is with `elem` is as follows:

```
filter' (`elem` ['a'..'z']) "Hell0!"
```

Which returns:

```
"ell"
```

In this particular example, is there a possible way of using `elem` as a prefix function instead of an infix function as a predicate?

In a more general sense, is there a way to supply only the second parameter in order to partially apply a prefix function?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either by creating a lambda (which will work for functions taking more than 2 parameters):

```
filter' (\a -> elem a ['a'..'z']) "Hell0!"
```

Or by using `flip`:

```
filter' (flip elem ['a'..'z']) "Hell0!"
```

Comment: Worth mentioning: the result is the same for all: `(\`elem\` v)`, `(\a -> elem a v)`, and `(flip elem v)`. Also, if I am not mistaken, you don't need the dollar sign.

Comment: @jd823592 I thought a point of it was to provide an equivalent solution, and so I didn't think that mentioning it was important. As for the dollar, I typically leave it for consistency and easier "function" and "data" separation, though I do realize it's very subjective.

Comment: I did not mean to suggest I disapproved. I totally agree with your answer, I just thought it might not be obvious and additional info may improve understanding of the matter.

Comment: @bartek-banachewicz, this is what I was looking for, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're after `flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`, which is in the prelude.

It can be implemented as `flip f = \b a -> f a b`.

Comment: @c-quilley, thanks a lot for your answer, even though I've chosen @bartek-banachewicz's proposition as the best solution, because it suggests two different paths, `flip` is indeed what I was looking for!